# How to set global node version? NVM

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nvm

I am trying to install MongoDB globally and I am getting an error that I need to use a different version of Node, but the error is showing I'm using version 10.0, but everything from my end is on 12.0.

This is a linux machine.

How do I set the node version for Mongo?

[image]

Comment: It appears to be an NPM issue, I used Yarn and it worked fine.

Comment: Not it's not an npm issue. It says to install mongodb your node version must be at least `v12.9.0`. But it seems like `yarn` just ignored this issue. You should update  node.

Comment: @h-sifat you very clearly didn't read what the console logged.